# Why Partial delegates are not allowed in C#?

Tags: c#, delegates

Recent interview question is

> If C# language allow us create partial delegates what are the consequences will you meet?

Help me to understand the reason.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are partial delegates ?

Comment: like partial class ...Partial keyword is applied on delegates

Comment: Makes no sense to have a partial delagate, its one line of code.

Comment: Negative votes are fine ,but it was an interview question

Comment: Do you mean curried delegates or curried functions with partial delegates?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should ask for clarification on this question. Because C# does support creating a delegate to a partial method as long as the partial method has been implemented. If this is what the question is implying then I guess '*the consequence you will meet*' is that the partial method must be implemented and not only defined.

The wording 'create partial delegate' does not make any sense since we have no definition of what a partial delegate might be.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't really make any sense to me.. when you define a delegate you need its signature, there's no point in a "partial" signature, it really says nothing